# Is there a design pattern that provides a more effective solution to this?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a problem\design issue with my system. I'll start from where I was:

I was creating a game engine in Java, and the game components commonly needed to reference the main\singleton instances of the game (world, filesystem etc...) - so I made my Game class a static global variable in the class Global. Whenever in code I need to open a file, I would write something like:

Global.game.getFilesystem().openFile(...)

There is simply no practical way to constantly passing around this Game object. I have been avoiding the singleton design pattern like the plague and would rather work my way around this one...

Anyway, now I have my GameCore library, which is that. I am now implementing a game with it. Obviously, in the process I would like to extend Game. The problem is, now my classes need a convenient way of accessing the same sort of resources - which is all fine - except that it can't use Global.game because Global.game can only be referenced as abstract class Game (even if it contains an instance of MyRpgGame), where I might need it of type MyRpgGame. Sure, I can type-cast, but it is messy and constant throughout the code. So the only solution I've come up with (albeit I really don't like it...) is something like this:

Where I reference game by going Game.game, or RpgGame.game ect...

```
public abstract class Game
{
    ...
    public static Game game = null;

    public Game()
    {
        if(game != null)
            throw new InitializationException("Cannot instantiate multiple instances of game.");
        game = this;

     ...
}
```

And then in my RpgGame, I hide the static field game in Game:

```
public class RpgGame extends Game
{
    public static RpgGame game = null;

    public RpgGame()
    {
        if(game != null)
            throw new InitializationException("Cannot instantiate multiple instances of game.");

        game = this;
    }
```

Comment: This is effectively the singleton pattern.  You aren't avoiding anything.

Comment: The question to ask yourself is why do many objects in your library need to reference to the game object?

Comment: @Flub because there is one game - and all the game components are naturally dependent on it. They use the same filesystem, and share the same game world.

Comment: @tieTYT that's mainly why I don't like this solution... I wouldn't argue though that it carries all the disadvantages of a singleton though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What you need is a dependency injection support**. It will eliminate all your issues, because dependency injection can be based on the interface,  instead of specific class, and you don't have to pass them around - they simply will be injected automatically.

Check out [Google Guice](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) or [Spring Framework](http://www.springsource.org/spring-framework). 
Google Guice is more lightweight but Spring Framework provides a lot of built-in functionality and has a huge ecosystem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is exactly what I am looking for. I'll do a bit of reading and give some others more time to respond before I mark this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm doing in my game that I'm writing in javascript.  This may be non-idiomatic in Java.  Keep in mind I'm trying to write my game in a functional programming style.  Here's how it works: I have one global variable named `gameState`.  It's only assigned in one method like this:

```
applyTick()
    global.gameState = tick(global.gameState)
    renderGameState(gameState)
```

The gameloop calls `applyTick()` over and over again.  In every single method except this one, you deal with a *local* `gameState` instance and most of my methods have a signature like this:

```
 gameState = methodName(gameState)
```

This way it's very easy to change the order of my operations.

If I need some new data like a `score,` I just add it to the `GameState` object and only the methods that care about `score` have to change.  Keep in mind I don't put any logic in the `GameState` object.  It's purely data.

I don't know if this is a good way to do things or a bad way.  I'm skeptical of it myself.  I keep on thinking I'll get to a point where this will become a maintenance nightmare and it'll be difficult to reason about my program.  But so far it's been exactly the opposite.  This "pattern" has worked out nicely for over 3 months.